# finding the rank of following matrix, please check it

Tags: matrices, determinant

\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1&2\\4&7&3&3\\1&7&2&1\end{pmatrix} please find its rank, I got the answer 3, is it correct? please check it

Comment: A quick RREF calculator says you are correct

Comment: sorry, suggest me what is this RREF calculator ?

Comment: a quick google search of "rref calculator" will provide you with a tool to check your work, so you dont need to check with someone every time

Comment: @user130512 If your calculator says the rank is 3 you should use a different one

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 yup, i must have entered a value that was off, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank cannot be 3, because the second row is the sum of the two other rows.

Comment: yup, the answer must be 2 as you are saying, anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @mahavir: You must have some error in computing those determinants, then.

Comment: ya ya I got the answer

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Do the following job:

$$-3R_3+R_1\to R_1, ~~~-4R_3+R_2\to R_2$$ or $$R_2-R_3=R_1$$